# Creating a linked list of cities using a struct class with given .h file c++

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, header-files

```
#ifndef COMMUNICATIONNETWORK_H
#define COMMUNICATIONNETWORK_H
#include <iostream>
    struct City{
    std::string cityName;
    std::string message;
    City *next;

    City(){}; // default constructor

    City(std::string initName, City *initNext, std::string initMessage)
    {
        cityName = initName;
        next = initNext;
        message = initMessage;
    }

};

class CommunicationNetwork
{
    public:
        CommunicationNetwork();
        ~CommunicationNetwork();
        void addCity(std::string, std::string);
        void buildNetwork();
        void transmitMsg(char *); //this is like a string
        void printNetwork();
    protected:
    private:
        City *head;
        City *tail;
};

#endif // COMMUNICATIONNETWORK_H
```

I was just wondering what exactly this .h does/sets up and how I would have to proceed in my CommunicationsNetwork.cpp as well as my main.cpp to construct a list of given cities.

Note: This code should eventually be able to add cities to the list, print out the cities in the linked list and transmit a message, but I'm just currently interested in trying to create the linked list.

Comment: I would guess you're supposed to implement the functions declared in `CommunicationNetwork`.

Comment: How did you do on the earlier assignments?

Comment: If you were given these, you should have also been given some description of what everything is and what they should do. To an outsider it's impossible to guess.

Answer (score 0):

As I see `CommunicationsNetwork.h` has declarations for struct and class, so in `CommunicationsNetwork.cpp` must be definitions for all member methods of `class CommunicationNetwork`, something like:

```cpp
        #include "CommunicationNetwork.h"
        . . . //  some other #include directives
        CommunicationNetwork::CommunicationNetwork(){
            . . . 
        }
        . . .
        void CommunicationNetwork::printNetwork()
        {
            . . .
        }
```

To use `CommunicationNetwork` class and `City` struct in the `main.cpp` you need:

1. Include h-file into `main.cpp` as `#include "CommunicationNetwork.h"`
2. Compile `CommunicationsNetwork.cpp` with `main.cpp` (i.e. link compiled files in one binary)

If you have not `CommunicationsNetwork.cpp` and your task is to write definitions for methods of class `CommunicationsNetwork` you have to start from designing algorithm for all the actions (I mean, think over how to build network, how to add a city, etc.).

Default constructor can be like:

```cpp
CommunicationNetwork::CommunicationNetwork()
{
     head = NULL;
     tail = NULL;
}
```

Destructor (i.e. `CommunicationNetwork::~CommunicationNetwork()`) have to remove all elements from your list and free memory allocated for elements storage.

Remember about checking value of `head` and `tail` when adding city to network (adding to empty list can be slightly different because after first element made a `head` is also a `tail`).

So, begin to write code and good luck!